# What Jenkins plugin can be used for .NET web site deployment?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, jenkins, web-deployment, microsoft-web-deploy

We use:
- SVN
- Jenkins
- MS Build plugin

We have several Web Form/MVC/Web services.

We are going to setup Microsoft Web Deploy and run bat file from Jenkins.

Maybe someone can suggest better way to do that or this looks like most effective solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*WebDeploy* is definetly the **right** way to deploy web applications.

Staring from *VS2010* targets for running web deploy in simple scenarious are "built-in" into the project files(and msbuild extension files on the PC). Starting from *VS2012* you can also use *Publish Profiles* feature which allows storing publish details in a simple file.  E.g. you can run something like that:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name> /p:Password=<insert-password> /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

Which will build the app and publish it using the `profile-name` publish profile.

- Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx) article's *"Creating a Publish Profile"* section to know more about creating Publish profiles.
- Have a look at this [post](http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/CommandLineWebProjectPublishing.aspx) by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi for reference on publish automation with VS 2012.
- There's also a good [series of blog posts](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_11.html) on automating deployments with TeamCity by Troy Hunt (he uses vs2010, so this might be helpful if you are using VS2010)

We were using bat files to run webdeploy commands directly when we were restricted to *.NET 3.5* and *VS2008* which didn't have project files web deploy integration.

Hope it helps,

Ivan